Posh-SSH Set-Item failing with generic error when uploading to apple school manager. Powershell
I have a script uploading to Apple school Manager. it will connect to the server and I can use get/set location commands to navigate around the upload server, however I can not set the item and only get a super generic error. I have a almost identical script uploading to clever and it works. any idea where to start looking?
I'm still not super versed in scripting I've pretty much just been leaning on the job so I may have quite a few issues below overall.
I have tried various kinds of things like variations on the upload path to setting the timeouts to swapping all the "" in the upload path to "/".
the server is a paramiko server based off the session information stored in $thissession.
the exception followed by the function:
TargetSite     : Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpFileAttributes RequestLStat(System.String)
Message        : Failure
Data           : {}
InnerException : 
HelpLink       : 
Source         : Renci.SshNet
HResult        : -2146233088
StackTrace     :    at Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpSession.RequestLStat(String path)
                    at Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.Exists(String path)
                    at SSH.SetSftpItem.ProcessRecord()
                    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()

Function Upload{
    $fileName = "$outputFolder\asm.zip"
    if (Test-Path $fileName) { Remove-Item $fileName }
    
    Compress-Archive -Path $outputFolder\* -DestinationPath $fileName

    $ftpFile = "<server path>\creds.json"
    $ftpCreds = Get-Content $ftpFile| ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable

    $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $ftpCreds.password -AsPlainText -Force
    $Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($ftpCreds.username, $Password)
    $SftpIp = $ftpCreds.uploadServer

    $ThisSession = New-SFTPSession -ComputerName $SftpIp -Credential $Credential -AcceptKey -ConnectionTimeout 120 -OperationTimeout 120 -Verbose -ErrorVariable SessionERR

    $remotePath = '/dropbox'
 
    try{
        Set-SFTPItem -SessionId ($ThisSession).SessionId -Path $fileName -Destination $remotePath -Force -Verbose -Debug
    }
    catch{

        ConvertTo-Json $_
    }
    finally{
        Remove-SFTPSession -SessionId ($ThisSession.SessionId)
        }
        #>
    } 

